# django formset not saving

Tags: python, django

**EDIT:** Turns out my form was not validating. I added print(formset.errors) as an else in my view, which revealed that I had a required field not being completed.

I am trying to manually render formset fields in a template, but the fields are not being saved when I submit.

My method works for a different formset based on another model, and as far as I can tell I haven't done anything differently. I tried a number of changes, but the issue seems to be {{ form.id }} in the template; when I change it to {{ form }}, I am able to save some of the fields.

As mentioned, this same set up works for another model/formset; when I make changes to a field and save, the page is refreshed and the model shows as updated. The code below is for the model/formset that is not working.

```
models.py

class Call(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    customer_number = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    tracking_source = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    tracking_number = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, 
    qualified_offer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    recorded_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def publish(self):
        self.recorded_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def t_number(self):
        return self.tracking_number[-4:]

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)

forms.py

class CallForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Call
        fields = ('name', 'customer_number', 'tracking_source', 'qualified_offer', 'recorded_date')


CallFormSet = modelformset_factory(Call, fields=('name', 'customer_number', 'tracking_source', 'recorded_date', 'qualified_offer'))

view.py

def call_list(request):

    if request.method == 'GET':
        formset = CallFormSet(queryset=Call.objects.all())
    elif request.method == "POST":
        formset = CallFormSet(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():
            for form in formset:
                if form.cleaned_data.get('name'):
                    form.save()
        return redirect('call_list')

    return render(request, 'webapp/call_list.html', {'formset': formset})

call_list.html

{% extends 'webapp/base.html' %}


{% block content %}

<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="">
<table style="width:100%" border="1">
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Qualified Offer</th>
    </tr>
{% csrf_token %}
{{ formset.management_form }}
{% for form in formset %}
    {{ form.id }}
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>{{form.name}}</label></td>
        <td>
            <label>{{form.qualified_offer}}</label>
            {% if form.qualified_offer.value %}
                <label>True</label>
            {% else %}
                <label>False</label>
            {% endif %}
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}

</table>
<div class="row spacer">
    <div class="col-4 offset-2">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Save</button>
    </div>
</div>

</form>
{% endblock %}
```

With the code above, the page refreshes but the model is unchanged. Again, if I render the formset with {{ form }} instead of {{ form.id }} it does save, but then I am unable to manually render the fields.

Comment: Where is form.qualified_offer defined?

Comment: sorry, added it back to the model. its in the code, there are just so many fields I missed it when stripping down to post here.

Comment: What do you mean by "unable to manually render the fields."?

Comment: I want to be able to render only the fields I want within a table, but as far as I know if I just use {{ form }] all the fields are rendered in a pre-defined way.

Comment: ah. question title was confusing me. I used [this resource](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/article/2017/08/19/how-to-render-django-form-manually.html). Wonderful guide.

Comment: thanks, I checked that out but it doesn't seem to help with formsets.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my form was not validating. I added print(formset.errors) as an else in my view, which revealed that I had a required field not being completed.